# VS 2017 RC generating an 0x8000ffff error when trying to debug xUnit tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xunit, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to debug my .NET Core xUnit tests in VS 2017 RC. I run my tests via the Test Explorer window. While right-clicking a test and selecting **Run Selected Tests** works fine, selecting **Debug Selected Tests** does not:

[image]

I'm at a loss at how to get past this. I have tried restarting VS, doing a clean build, removing the `.vs/` folder, and even updating to a newer build of VS 2017. However, nothing so far has worked. Does anyone have suggestions for how I can work around this? Thanks!

**edit:** My project has a Git repo [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/BasicCompiler/tree/44e148000c21174f0872a7a423f997955268d045), so if you want to you're free to clone it and see if you can repro for yourself. The test assembly is in `src/BasicCompiler.Tests/`.

Comment: Is the `c#` tag necessary if you already use the `.net` tag in this context?

Comment: @devRicher I think this question is related to both C# and .NET because the tests are failing over a C# project.

Comment: Compare to my project https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/9392c72021be63b17866351ab5093492fdb51365/Tests/Tests.NetStandard.csproj I can only see the version of xunit is not up-to-date.

Comment: Did you try to create new project and write test to make sure that it is not your project setting that causes the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375869/visual-studio-crashes-when-i-debug-a-project-with-a-certain-form-open-in-design  Not sure if this guy's answer will help, but I hope it does. The error code is "catastrophic failure", which is super generic. Try also unloading and reloading the project?

Comment: Use the "Report a Problem feature: found under the Help -> Send Feedback. I've gotten responses from the Visual Studio team previously that have helped (by providing my email with the report).

Comment: I would monitor the memory consumption while debugging

Answer (score 7):

In my case with Visual Studio 2017 release version the unit test project failed with this error because for some reason the unit test project had a launchsettings.json file under the project "properties" folder. Deleting it resolved the debugging issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Visual Studio as an administrator, it might resolve the issue.

In case you don't know how:
Right click on the application icon, right click on the applications name and select Run as Administrator.

Comment: Probably not the solution

Answer (score 0):

If nothing helps try complete uninstall and reinstall of Visual Studio. Errors in upgrades cause issue sometimes. Ideally IDE should prompt errors and ask you to fix them but I have noticed Visual Studio does not do that; even when you go to updater and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating Visual Studio 2017 to 15.9.6

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting vs worked for me...